# Фоновое обновление данных

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Есть приложение (радио). Если приложение в фоне - музыка играет, но если вдруг теряется сеть, то воспроизведение не может сделать реконект, ибо как я правильно понял, в бекграунг режиме приложение активно только 30 секунд. для того чтобы оно реконектилось приходится разблокировать устройство и тогда оно нормально коннектится и дальше играет.

В `required background modes` выставил `App downloads content from the network` но это не помогает

Comment: предположу, что `background fetch` должен помочь. Проверять reachability и запускать аудио если интернет есть. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-7-sdk-working-with-background-fetch--mobile-20520

Comment: Указано ли App plays audio в бекграундовых режимах? Без него действительно приложение будет затухать. `Background fetch` точно не спасёт, ибо его вызовы нерегулярны

Comment: @Sega-Zero да, указано. reachability мне тоже на сколько я знаю не поможет, так как ну проверит оно есть соединение или нет, а дальше то нужно чтобы коннект произошел, т.е. нужно, когда сеть теряется и происходит попытка реконекта, как-то разбудить приложение. а вот как - не знаю

Comment: Никак. Приложение не может выдать себе квант времени по желанию. Есть ровно 2 легальных способа выполнять код в фоне - ключ для фонового аудио и флаг voip. Есть лазейки в виде апдейта геолокации, фоновое скачивание через NSURLSession, silent пуши, но они опять же дадут квант не более 30 секунд. Флага с аудио должно хватать, если проверяется на устройстве, в симуляторе он емнип не работает

Comment: @Sega-Zero видел совет про NSURLSession. везде где есть в проекте NSURLConnection поменял на NSURLSession. но осталась одна строка и она помоему самая важная conn = [[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self] retain]; как её переделать под NSURLSession

Comment: @Sega-Zero я просто новичек, поэтому и такие вопросы) проект переделываю из исходников с github

Comment: В целом, `NSURLSession` вкупе с `[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:]` позволяют забыть про обрыв сети, ибо заботу об этом берёт на себя демон nsurlsessiond. Но я, честно говоря, не очень понимаю, зачем вообще скачивать поток самому - ведь есть `AVAudioPlayer`, который умеет читать напрямую из сети, есть `MPMoviewPlayerController`, который также умеет это делать. Или у вас радио специфичное, типа rtmp потока?

Comment: @Sega-Zero честно не отвечу на этот вопрос. исходники брал вот эти [ссылка](https://github.com/le0pard/PsyRadioIOS)

Comment: Я бы не советовал использовать их в качестве учебного материала, ибо используется уже давно окаменевшее апи. Используйте `AVPlayer`, `AVAudioPlayer` или `MPMoviePlayerViewController` - они все умеют принимать на вход урл на mp3 поток. Примеров в сети много.

Comment: @Sega-Zero спасибо за совет) будем думать)